# List Queues/Topics of Azure Service Bus using Rest API with SharedAccessKey

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to list the Queues/Topics in an Azure Service Bus using the REST API.

When I try to connect I just get back a blank feed saying "This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available".

I am using the RootManageSharedAccessKey in the portal (for dev only, I can create a more restricted key later) so it should have all the access rights that I need, I just can't seem to get it to return anything. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/entities-discovery) documentation seems to suggest that this will work, but there's no actual working examples, just theoretical responses.

I have tried doing a GET request with the signature in the URL like this:

```
https://myservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/Queues;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=MYSHAREDACCESSKEY
```

I have also tried doing it like this:

```
https://myservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources
```

and then setting the Authorization header to

```
WRAP access_token="MYSHAREDACCESSKEY="
```

Both times I just get this back

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title>
    <subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle>
    <id>uuid:6a5d438d-1793-451b-be41-XXXXXXXXXXXX;id=XXXXXX</id>
    <updated>2020-06-28T13:03:04Z</updated>
    <generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator>
</feed>
```

If I change the url slightly to be:

```
https://myservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/Queues/
```

I get a slightly different response back of:

```
<Error>
    <Code>401</Code>
    <Detail>claim is empty. TrackingId:c40a2bd2-490d-4b5b-adde-33bc89aa84ff_G36, SystemTracker:myservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net:$Resources/Queues, Timestamp:2020-06-28T13:27:40</Detail>
</Error>
```

Which seems to suggest that I am not authorised, or I am missing something. If I add an acutual queue name to the end of that url, it goes back to the original response.

I believe there is another way to get this information by using subscription ids and pem keys...  using the management urls `(https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription ID}/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/{Namespace}/Topics/)`
but this should all be possible using the format above, I just can't figure out the exact format required.

EDIT/UPDATE: If I don't include my auth claim, the result is exactly the same, suggesting that it's not seeing my auth claim or it's invalid. However if I include it, and just make it the token, without the WRAP bit at the start, I get an exception saying

```
<Error>
    <Code>401</Code>
    <Detail>MalformedToken: Invalid authorization header: The request is missing WRAP authorization credentials. TrackingId:7be2d7f0-c165-4658-8bf1-ea104c43defc_G28, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2020-06-28T13:33:09</Detail>
</Error>
```

So it's like it's reading it then ignoring it?

Comment: Where are you creating shared access signature? You would need to do that in order to use the REST API.

Comment: @Guarav - Just creating it in the Portal under the service bus > settings > Shared access policies. Currently using the default RootManageSharedAccessKey which should have full rights to the service bus (It's what I would connect with as an app or using service bus explorer)

Comment: Behind the scenes, an authorization header is created using the shared access key and that’s used for authorizing the requests. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri-AIS you are correct, I thought the token provided in the portal would be enough. I didn't realise that I have to create the token myself using the access key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list queues or topics  we can use [Azure service bus service rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/enumeration) or [Azure Resource Manager Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces). For more details,  please refer to the following steps

- **Azure service bus service rest api**

1. Generate SAS token. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas)

   For example, I use python to create sas token

```
import hmac
import time
import hashlib
import base64
import urllib
sb_name='bowmantest'
// your entity path such as $Resources/topics (list topics) $Resources/queues(list queues)
topic='$Resources/topics' 
url=urllib.parse.quote_plus("https://{}.servicebus.windows.net/{}".format(sb_name,topic))
sas_value='' // your share access key 
sas_name='RootManageSharedAccessKey' // your share access rule name 
expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
to_sign =(url + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8') 
sas = sas_value.encode('utf-8')
signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
auth_format = 'SharedAccessSignature sig={0}&se={1}&skn={2}&sr={3}'
auth=auth_format.format(signature,expiry,sas_name,url)
print(auth)
```

2. Call the rest API

1). list Queues

```
GET https://<namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/queues

Authorization <sas token>
```

[image]

2). List topics

```
GET https://<namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/topics

Authorization <sas token>
```

[image]

- **Azure Resource Manager Rest API**

1. create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role to the sp(I use Azure CLI)

```
az login
#it will create a service principal and assign contributor role to the sp
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "jonsp2"
```

[image]

2. Get Azure AD token

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<app id>
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&client_secret=<app password>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

3. call the rest API

List Queues

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}/queues?api-version=2017-04-01

Authorization Bearer <AD token>
```

[image]